# SQL Server - db_owner user can't see sys schemas

Tags: sql-server-2012

these is a user in database XXX_service (it's technical account) and it has set "Server role" - public and and user mapping as dbo_owner for one database.

Programmer sent logs and there are errors like this one:

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure sp_OACreate, Line 1
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_OACreate', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
```

I think it is necessary to rise rights but i thought db_owner for concrete database >= sysadmin. Am i wrong? Sorry for my bad english, thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i resolved it. Sometimes google first, sorryu for post :)

It was necessary allow Ole Automation Procedures:

```
    sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

And then grant rights to user:

```
grant exec on schema::sys to [USER]
```